# Parse array data and remove the first and last character

Tags: php, arrays

Does anyone know if there is a way to remove the first and last character of array data.

Basically the [ and ] from the data that is returned.

Comment: What kind of data are you talking about? Can you give an example? Maybe you want `json_decode`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: json decode was what I need since it was data from a curl request for a json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your comment confirmed it:

It sounds like you want to use [`json_decode` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). If your data is JSON, then don't try to parse it manually.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($array as $index => $d){
    $array[$index] = substr($d, 1, -1);
}
```